# Error while migrating Campaign reports between orgs

Tags: migration-tool, campaign-member

I get the following error while migrating a Campaign report between orgs using the migration tool.

> reportTypes/Campaigns_with_Campaign_Member_Information.reportType --
>   Error: In field: field - no CustomField named
>   Lead.Board_Committee_Assignee__c found

Here's the corresponding snippet from the report metadata definition, retrieved from the source org.

> ```
>   <columns>
>         <checkedByDefault>false</checkedByDefault>
>         <field>Board_Committee_Assignee__c</field>
>         <table>Campaign.CampaignMembers</table>
>     </columns>
> ```

I've verified that Board_Committee_Assignee__c is a custom field on CampaignMember; its a Lookup(Contact). Does this have something to do with CampaignMembers defaulting to Leads and not Contacts ? Is there anyway of changing that so the report can be migrated ?

Comment: It would make sense that this would cause an error if the field doesn't exist on Lead and the box is checked by default, but it appears that it's not. Have you looked to see if the field also exists as a lookup on Lead in the source org? Have you tried changing the default to checked to see if that resolves the issue for you?

Comment: It's only defined as a Lookup on Contact in the source org. How do I change the default CampaignMember from Leads to Contacts ?

Comment: Chances are that you have record type(s) assigned to Campaigns that includes setting the Lead as the Default CampaignMember Type. You'd need to edit that RecordType to change it to Contact. However, if that's the case, you probably just need to recreate the RecordTypes in the other org where you're trying to migrate the report to eliminate the issues you're having. Something isn't the same between the two orgs in your Campaign settings. Look in Setup to see what's different.

Comment: Nope. The record types assigned to Campaign in both are identical :(